# Trying to get NGINX to work with PCs that aren't on local network

Tags: nginx

My Knowledge on this: I feel very competent with OBS software, but have absolutely no idea what I'm doing in NGINX.

What I'm trying to do: Allow a PC that isn't on my local network to connect to NGINX rtmp server (no idea if i'm using correct terminology as I have no idea what I'm doing). I then use the rtmp link as a video stream source thingy in OBS.

How Far I got: I have added the RTMP link into OBS as a video source, no problem. I managed to connect to the RTMP link using the local IP address of the machine running NGINX, but when trying to do this using that same computers public IP it fails to connect.

So I am testing this with two pcs on the same network. Am I correct that my friend would need to use the public ip address for that machine to connect to the rtmp link? If so what can I do to allow external connections?

Comment: As always, forward the port on the public address to the appropriate machine.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure nginx listens on all IP addresses of the server (the "listen" directive). If one of those addresses is a public one, anyone from the Internet should be able to connect to it as long as there are no firewalls in between.

If the network is not configured properly though, it may very well be impossible to connect to a public interface of the server from within the local network. That would suggest incorrect routing table on the server.

In order to be able to connect to (any) IP address, a "route" must exist from the source to the destination.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. So I have taken a screenshot of what I believe is the file I need to configure to do what you are saying, though I'm not certain. What specifically here would I change and to what?

https://imgur.com/a/k5DRt